# Saving an object/entity in a Playframework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

Hi all i am new to playframework and JPA

1st i created a User entity bean as below

```
@Entity

@Table(name="m_users")

public class AppUser {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue 
public  int uid;

@Required
@MaxSize(100)
public @Column(name="user_name") String userName;

@Required
@MaxSize(20)
public @Column(name="pass") String password;

public AppUser(int uid, String userName, String password) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

then i created a datamanager that saves the content in to the in memory of playframework
as shown below

```
public class DataManager extends JapidController {
    public static void cuser() {

        AppUser user = new AppUser();
        user.password = "secret";
        user.userName = "jonathan@gmail.com";      
        user.save();
        renderJapid(user);
    }
}
```

Following error is what i am getting

> PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of models.AppUser.uid
>
> play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of models.AppUser.uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AppUSer class should look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "m_users")
public class AppUser extends Model {

    @Required
    @MaxSize(100)
    public @Column(name = "user_name")
    String userName;

    @Required
    @MaxSize(20)
    public @Column(name = "pass")
    String password;

    public AppUser(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

As you see, it should extends Model, which already implements generated id value.

You can read more about that [here](http://www2.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide2).

Comment: In the situation if I have another class say message where i need reference to from user and to user. ???

Comment: Look at the Post class on the page mentioned in above answer and give attention to @ManyToOne annotation....

Comment: @PrimosK I have a similar problem.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295695/could-not-set-a-field-value-by-reflection-setter

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Hibernate is looking for a setter for your uid property. Have you provided this setter or were you just planning to provide direct access to a public property?